# WQO agent and LotusScript

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript

I am trying to create a div tag in WQO agent using Lotusscript as below :

In my form it is blank form

```
Dim session As New NotesSession

    Set thisdb = session.CurrentDatabase
    Set doccontext = session.DocumentContext

    Print | </form> _
            <form name ="thisform"  _
        <form name ="thisform" > _
        <div id ="thisform"> _
            Please wait while we proces your request ........<img src='./please-wait.gif' width=50 height=50></img> _
            </div> _
            </form> |
```

However this outputs nothing, am I doing anythign wrong here ?

Edit :

Basically I wanted to print view html view with button to delete the selected records, but before I want to make sure that please wait is being displayed before it prints HTML view.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [help page for WebQueryOpen and WebQuerySave agents](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ABOUT_RUNNING_AGENTS_BEFORE_WEB_USERS_OPEN_OR_SAVE_DOCUMENTS.html), you can't use a print statement in a WQO agent to send HTML to a browser.

> A WebQueryOpen event runs the agent before Domino® converts a document
>   to HTML and sends it to the browser. *Domino ignores any output
>   produced by the agent in this context.*

You need to put a field in the appropriate place on the form, mark it as pass-through HTML, and have your WQO agent save the HTML into the item value for that field.